# Constant time string equality test return value

Tags: c, cryptography

Looking for a constant time string equality test I found that most of them use bit trickery on the return value. For example this piece of code:

```
int ctiszero(const void* x, size_t n)
{
  volatile unsigned char r = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    r |= ((unsigned char*)x)[i];
  }
  return 1 & ((r - 1) >> 8);
}
```

What is the purpose of `return 1 & ((r - 1) >> 8);`? Why not a simple `return !r;`?

Comment: Constant time how? Equal to what? The term "string equality" implies that two strings are to be compared for equality, but your example function takes only one string argument?

Comment: I think the purpose is to return either `1` or `0`, and nothing else. It's equivalent to equally confusing `!!!r`.

Comment: All this function does is to make a bitwise mush of all the contents in an array, then subtract - 1 from the mush and check if the MSB is set. How this makes sense or have anything to do with strings, I have no idea.

Comment: And note that this function isn't constant-time, it's time-complexity is O(n). It depends on `n`. Constant time would be O(1). Furthermore, the code doesn't compare strings for equality, it tests if an array is all zero or not.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In cryptography bibliography they call it "constant time". Not in the sense of big O notation, but in the sense that it won't take an execution time related to the contents of the strings as in the naive comparison. Useful to prevent some side-channel attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in one of my comments, this functions checks if an array of arbitrary bytes is zero or not. If all bytes are zero then `1` will be returned, otherwise `0` will be returned.

If there is at least one non-zero byte, then `r` will be non-zero as well. Subtract `1` and you get a value that is zero or positive (since `r` is `unsigned`). Shift all bits off of `r` and the result is zero, which is then masked with `1` resulting in zero, which is returned.

If all the bytes are zero, then the value of `r` will be zero as well. But here comes the "magic": In the expression `r - 1` the value of `r` undergoes what is called [*usual arithmetic conversion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions), which leads to the value of `r` to become [*promoted*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to an `int`. The value is still zero, but now it's a *signed* integer. Subtract `1` and you will have `-1`, which with the usual [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) notation is equal to `0xffffffff`. Shift it so it becomes `0x00ffffff` and mask with `1` results in `1`. Which is returned.

Comment: But isn't right shift of a negative signed number an implementation-defined behavior? '-1 >> 8' can be  '0x00FFFFFF' or '0xFFFFFFFF' depending on implementation. Why to introduce this strange operation instead of directly masking with 1?

Comment: @user3368561 The shift is needed when there is one or more non-zero bytes in the array (i.e. when `r != 0`)

Comment: OK, I see. Low byte doesn't need to be 0xFF. We shift it right to get next sign extended byte that will be always 0x00 or 0xFF.

Comment: @user3368561 It is _implementation-defined behavior_.  If `int` is involved as the rare _sign-magnitude_, `1 & ((r - 1) >> 8)` always returns 0.  Still, a reasonable risk in 2018.

Comment: The code would be better if the final statement were `return 1 & ((r - 1u) >> 8);`, thus avoiding implementation-defined shift behavior.

Answer (score 1):

With *constant time* code, typically code that may branch (and incur run-time time differences), like `return !r;` is avoided.

Note that a well optimized compiler may emit the exact same code for `return 1 & ((r - 1) >> 8);` as `return !r;`.  This exercise is therefore, at best, code to coax the compiler input emitting *constant time* code.

---

**What about uncommon platforms?**

`return 1 & ((r - 1) >> 8);` is well explained by [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48766868/2410359) good answer when `int` is 8-bit 2's complement - something that is very common.

With 8-bit `unsigned char`, and `r > 0`, `r-1` is non-negative and `1 & ((r - 1) >> 8)` returns 0 even if `int` is 2's complement, 1's complement or sign-magnitude, 16-bit, 32-bit etc.

When `r == 0`, `r-1` is -1.  It is *implementation define behavior* what `1 & ((r - 1) >> 8)` returns.   It returns 1 with  `int` as 2's complement or 1's complement, but 0 with sign-magnitude.

```
// fails with sign-magnitude (rare)
// fails when byte width > 8 (uncommon)
return 1 & ((r - 1) >> 8);
```

---

Small changes can fix to work as desired in more cases<sup>1</sup>.  Also see [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766303/constant-time-string-equality-test-return-value/48770151#comment84540114_48766868)

By insuring `r - 1` is done using `unsigned` math, `int`  encoding is irrelevant.

```
//                v--- add u   v--- shift by byte width
return 1 & ((r - 1u) >> CHAR_BIT);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Somewhat rare: When `unsigned char` size is the same as `unsigned`, OP's code and this fix fail.  If wider math integer was available, code could use that: e.g.: `return 1 & ((r - 1LLU) >> CHAR_BIT);`

Answer (score 0):

That's shorthand for r > 128 or zero. Which is to say, it's a non-ASCII character.  If r's high bit is set subtracting 1 from it will leave the high bit set unless the high bit is the **only** bit set.  Thus greater than 128 (0x80) and if r is zero, underflow will set the high bit.

The result of the for loop then is that if any bytes have the high bit set, or if all of the bytes are zero, 1 will be returned.  But if all the non-zero bytes do not have the high bit set 0 will be returned.

Oddly, for a string of all 0x80 and 0x00 bytes 0 will still be returned.  Not sure if that's a "feature" or not!

Comment: `r - 1` is an `int` subtraction, not an `unsigned char` subtraction.  `1 & ((r - 1) >> 8)` returns the same as `!r`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing that out!  I wonder if in the history of this little code snippet someone changed r to unsigned.  I've seen this idiom in device drivers before, and my tests confirm that if r is a signed char the result is as as I indicated, except that it catches 0x80 as well, thereby returning 1 for any string containing any high-bit-set char or only containing zeros, a useful but old-fashioned definition of "uninteresting" in an ASCII context.  With r as an unsigned char, this is, indeed, a highly peculiar way of returning !r.

Comment: NMDV, Maybe it was `char` and not `unsigned char`.  Code is striving for "constant time" and so employs the "highly peculiar way of returning !r".  What is something of a false assurance is that with `1 & ((r - 1) >> 8)`, a compiler could still emit branching code that does exactly `return !r` and so not meet code's hidden goal.